# Cannot complete wordpress setup aftern installing it with Docker Desktop + WSL2

Tags: wordpress, docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am trying to install wordpress using Docker Desktop and WSL2.
I was able to compose an image creating the following `docker-compose.yml` file and then running `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

(This is taken from the [official wordpress image's page on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress). I have change the default environment variables for `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_NAME` but they were set equal to  `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_DATABASE` respectively.)

Back to Docker Desktop, I ran the container, which seems to work correctly because when I got to `localhost:8080` I find Wordpress' first setup process. However, when I plug-in the database name, username, password and host that I used in the file I get the error "Error establishing a database connection".

I tried the following for as Database host, but none worked: `localhost`, `localhost:8080`, `localhost:80` and `db`.

Any idea?

Comment: How about `db:8080`? Did you try that one as well?

Comment: Just tried and it does not work